# Grammatical Unit İdentifying Problem

Tags: phrases, adverbial-phrases

> Fearing  the  old  woman  would  be  frightened  by  their
> being  alone,  and  not  hoping  that  the  sight  of  him  would
> disarm her suspicions, he took hold of the door and drew
> it towards him

The sections `Fearing  the  old  woman  would  be  frightened  by  their  being  alone` and `not  hoping  that  the  sight  of  him  would  disarm her suspicions` seems like adverbial phrases for the verb of the following sentence, but ı am not sure.

Comment: They are both gerund-participial clauses functioning as supplementary adjuncts. Note the supplements are not modifiers.

Comment: wow, thanks. I learned the language by listening and reading but didn't learn in-depth grammatical concepts. Could you suggest some sources.

Comment: I've posted an answer that contains a link to a useful resource.

Comment: What is the source of your quoted excerpt? The phrase *not hoping* in that context is not idiomatic - it makes it sound like he *doesn't* want to "disarm her suspicions," but it's clear that the **intended** meaning is that he *does* want to but *doesn't* think it's likely that he will. The idiomatic way of expressing that idea is, "*not daring to hope* that the sight of him...")

Comment: That information should have been given in the question.

Comment: Stick to the question, which is about grammar, not semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*Fearing the old woman would be frightened by their being alone], and*
> *[not hoping that the sight of him would disarm her suspicions], he took*
> *hold of the door and drew it towards him.*

The first comma marks the bracketed coordination of clauses as a supplementary adjunct. Supplements are loosely attached expressions set off by intonation and punctuation, presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

More specifically, it's here an adjunct of implicated reason. It gives the reason for the matrix (overall) situation.

This resource may help. [link](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar/EB0ABC6005935012E5270C8470B2B740/adjuncts-modifiers-and-supplements/E56EF25F189AD293220FC3C337238FF3)